# Unity3d: server delay in spawning networked RigidBody projectiles

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm following the [official multiplayer networking tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/multiplayer-networking), but I'm having some trouble with the "bullets".

Each bullet prefab is spawned on the server-side through a command, according to the position of a spawn point on the player prefab. The basic system works well, but for all players except the host there is a large amount of lag between the location of the spawn point and the spawned bullet.

The bullets are spawned correctly according to the player's location on the server, as expected. However, this is behind the player's client position.

Is there a solution to this? Should I be using RigidBody at all? I've seen methods which use raycasting for projectiles which may be an improvement, but I would like to be able to see the projectiles travel through the air. Any help would be very appreciated!

For reference, the relevant PlayerController code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : NetworkBehaviour {

    public float speed;
    public float turnSpeed;

    public GameObject bulletPrefab;
    public Transform bulletSpawn;

    void Update () {
        if (!isLocalPlayer) {
            return;
        }

        float power = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * speed;
        float turn = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * turnSpeed;

        transform.Rotate(0, turn, 0);
        transform.Translate (power, 0, 0);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space)) {
            CmdFire ();
        }
    }

    [Command]
    void CmdFire() {
        var bullet = (GameObject)Instantiate (bulletPrefab, bulletSpawn.position, bulletSpawn.rotation);

        bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = bullet.transform.forward * 6;

        NetworkServer.Spawn (bullet);

        Destroy (bullet, 2.0f);
    }

}
```